# MYSQL SELECT on two tables with MIN Value

Tags: mysql, join, min

I have two tables, one is a products table, and the other is an offers table for different vendors offering the same product.

Table1:

```
sku   name
----|-----
a   | Iphone
b   | Galaxy 5
c   | Nexus 6
```

Table2:

```
sku   price   vendor
----|-------|--------
a   | 5.00  | storeX
a   | 6.00  | storeY
a   | 7.00  | storeZ
b   | 15.00 | storeP
b   | 20.00 | storeQ
b   | 30.00 | storeR
c   | 11.00 | storeD
c   | 12.00 | storeF
c   | 13.00 | storeG
```

I am trying to run a SELECT on these tables so I can get the lowest offer for each item. So my result would be:

```
sku   price    vendor
----|--------|--------
a   | 5.00   | storeX
b   | 15.00  | storeP
c   | 11.00  | stored
```

I have tried `SELECT table1.sku,table2.price FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.sku = table1.sku WHERE table2.sku IN ('a','b','c');`
But that just give me all offers. Any help with this query is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need two queries: one to determine the min price per product, and then a parent query to select the other fields related to that min price:

```
SELECT table2.*, table1.name
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN  (
   SELECT MIN(price) AS min, sku
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY sku
) AS child ON ((table2.price = child.min) AND (table2.sku = child.sku))
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table2.sku = table1.sku)
```

This also has the advantage of showing if multiple stores have the same minimum price.

Comment: One thing I didn't write on the original post was that I need some data from table1, like the name of the product with the results. Example:

`sku   price    vendor   name
----|--------|--------|----------
a   | 5.00   | storeX   | Iphone
b   | 15.00  | storeP   | Galaxy 5
c   | 11.00  | storeD   | Nexus 6`

Comment: easy enough, just join in the other table... fixed up the answer to do that.